# grep text after keyword with unknown spaces and remove comments

Tags: bash

I am having trouble saving variables from file using grep/sed/awk.
The text in file.txt is on the form:

```
NUM_ITER                = 1000 # Number of iterations
NUM_STEP               = 1000
```

And I would like to save these to bash variables without the comments.

So far, I have attempted this:

```
grep -oP "^NUM_ITER[ ]*=\K.*#" file.txt
```

which yields

```
 1000 #
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk`, like this:

```
awk -F'[=[:blank:]#]+' '$1 == "NUM_ITER" {print $2}' file
```

To store it in a variable:

```
NUM_ITER=$(awk -F'[=[:blank:]#]+' '$1 == "NUM_ITER" {print $2}' file)
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as a line can only contain a single match, this is easy with `sed`.

```
sed -n '# Remove comments
        s/[ ]*#.*//
        # If keyword found, remove keyword and print value
        s/^NUM_ITER[ ]*=[ ]*//p' file.txt
```

This can be trimmed down to a one-liner if you remove the comments.

```
sed -n 's/[ ]*#.*//;s/^NUM_ITER[ ]*=[ ]*//p' file.txt
```

The `-n` option turns off printing, and the `/p` flag after the final substitution says to print that line after all only if the substitution was successful.